# How to convert a list of dates into the AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a list of about 20 dates all formated like

```
August 24,2011
```

How would i go about creating  a list of all of these dates and setting them to the alarm manager,

So for example... Today is the 25, if a date in the AlarmManager is set to 25, a notification is made.

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a date first, using a formatter. Then get the timestamp from the date object using [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29). Pass the timestamp to `AlarmManager` and specify the `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm type. Something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(sdf);
long timestamp = date.getTime();

AlarmManager am = ...;
PendingIntent pi = ...;
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timestamp, pi);
```

Do keep in mind that, alarms are not persistent, so setting alarms too far in the future is not reliable: if the user reboots your phone (or kills your app/service), the alarms will be cleared. To register alarms on reboot, create a broadcast receiver for `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Comment: Could you provide an example with code? And also how could i make it where when the phone is rebooted the alarms are reset?

Comment: Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your date. As for handling reboots, you need to register a broadcast receiver for `BOOT_COMPLETED' and register your alarms there.